# API data not appearing in component but shows in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a rather simple API call to (https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers) and displaying fetched data in the component, but somehow the data is not getting displayed on the page, but when I console log it the data is displayed correctly.

```
const Comp= () => {
  const [item, setItem] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setItem(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {item.map((beer) => {
        const { name, tagline } = beer;
       
          <p>{name}</p>;
 
        console.log(name);
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You don't return anything from your `item` mapping. Return the JSX you want to render (i.e. `return <p>{name}</p>`) and don't forget to add a React key to the mapped elements. Below I've simplified to an implicit return.

You should also remove the console log from the render return as "render" methods are to be pure functions without side-effects, such as console logging. Either log the fetch result in the promise chain or use an `useEffect` hook to log the updated state.

```
useEffect(() => console.log(item), [item]);

...

return (
  <div>
    {item.map(({ id, name }) => (
      <p key={id}>{name}</p>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

[image: Edit api-data-not-appearing-in-component-but-shows-in-console]

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value from inside `.map` method like:

```
return (<p>{name}</p>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the JSX elements in your map.

```
   const Comp= () => {
  const [item, setItem] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setItem(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {item.map((beer) => {
        const { name, tagline } = beer;
       
         return <p>{name}</p>;
 
        console.log(name);
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```